# FTP upload from an in-experienced developer

Tags: html, css, ftp

Hoping you can help. I am in the very early days of developing a website and have learnt the basis of HTML and CSS.

I have uploaded my code via an FTP client, but I cannot see the pictures. I have copied across into a folder next to the .html files, but they do not show on the web.

Fully appreciate that this is likely to be an easy question to answer, but can anyone help to explain where I am going wrong?

Code - https://jsbin.com/vaxeqofota/1/edit?html,css,output

Thanks
Lewis

Comment: Almost certainly a path issue. Do you have a link to the live page?

Comment: You need to add forward slashes to the beginning of the image paths to make them absolute. "/images/etc/.jpg"

Comment: Also, if it helps. When I click view my .html file in a web browser I can see the pictures perfectly. It is only when I try to upload the html and pictures to FTP that they do not show

Comment: I've fixed it! Didn't realise that FTP was case sensitive. Thanks anyway